# MySQL error: "The server quit without updating PID file"

Tags: mysql, macos

I know this is a widelly answered question but I cannot find one solution that apply to my case.
On OSX El Capitan, I recently switched from a MAMP install to a "manual" install of MySQL, using the dmg package (version 5.7.11).
Now I want to modify the `datadir` to a custom location ; it used to work but I stopped the server and it doesn't want to start anymore. I tried launching it using:

```
sudo mysql.server start
sudo mysqld_safe
```

...but I always get this error: `The server quit without updating PID file (/Users/xxx/Documents/dev/MySQL/data/xxx.pid)`. But it starts whan I set back the `datadir` to its original location! (which is /usr/local/mysql/data)
First time I had this issue it was clearly documented in the .err file (`error 13` if I remember well, which is an access problem) and it was fixed by the magic combination of `sudo chown -R _mysql:wheel data/` and `sudo chmod -R 777 data/`. Now both original and custom datadir have the **same owners** (user and group) and **same read/write permissions**. But server will start for one and not for the other? And the .err file only logs:

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Users/xxx/Documents/dev/MySQL/data
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Users/xxx/Documents/dev/MySQL/data/xxx.pid ended
```

Which doesn't helps me much.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you check in the old and new locations for an error log?

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot
I did: the one from original MySQL location is full of warnings but nothing related to a pid file, the one from "custom" location only contains the 2 lines I already mentionned. Both have the same name (which isn't my user name, either computer's name... don't really know where it does come from in fact)